# Maas, Juju & Openstack, - "Unable to create the image"

Tags: juju, openstack

I can't create an image on Openstack, I receive this issue:

> Unable to create the image

[image]

I've get the image of U18.04 [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img)

The entire environment has been built used Maas/Juju and all the procedure seems to be went well.

[image]

any suggest? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that issue using this post, the problem was on ceph-osd

[ceph-osd No block devices detected using current configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074575/ceph-osd-no-block-devices-detected-using-current-configuration)

[image]